# Specify different broadcast IPs for different Windows machines

Tags: windows, networking, internet, ip-address, ipv4

I run some high-frequency trading software from home across multiple accounts. Sometimes during very volatile conditions, I run into issues with rate limits restricted by IP address.

I was assuming I could get a batch of IP addresses, which I've done, and split the accounts across different computers to reduce the likelihood of hitting rate limits.

Is there a way I can assign a public IP to be used for a specific Windows 10 machine, for both sending and receiving data?

I guess the control of this may be router related. I'm using a FRITZ!Box 7530, supplied by Zen.

Comment: Broadcasting does not work across the public Internet, so your question doesn't make sense. Also, all your private hosts use the very same public IPv4 address (the router's) and jumping hosts isn't really visible to the outside. For IPv6, all hosts use the same /56 or so prefix, the situation is the same.

Answer (score 1):

> I run into issues with rate limits restricted by IP address.

Bring the issue of your high volume up with the entity running the API. A professional will negotiate in good faith, possibly paying for the privilage. Dodging rate limiting is not polite and may be against their terms of service.

Also, implement IPv6 to get public IPs for every host. Having a personal /48 doesn't solve the problem of one host pushing too many requests. But it does remove the need for NAT.

Comment: Using multiple IPs was a suggestion from my account manager as at the time I brought up the issue their IT department wasn't willing to increase limits on individual accounts. The site has over 50m monthly active users, me using 2 IPs clearly isn't going to be a major problem. I was asking if there was a technical solution, not for a lesson in morality.

Comment: That the multiple IP addresses solution was proposed by the service would have been useful information in your question. Unfortunately, previously other people have asked similar questions on Server Fault that definitely were dodging limits not in good faith. Follow the documentation of your host OS for how to assign a public IP address. For more specific help, edit your question to add details: network diagram, high level how the application works, and what your thoughts are on multiple computers distributed workload vs multiple interfaces.